# How can I make ion-back-button skip previous page?

Tags: ionic4

I have three pages (A, B and C) in my Ionic4 application. Page C has an ion-back-button.

I'm trying to implement the following navigation flow (using Angular router and the ion-back-button):

A -> B -> C, and then navigating back from C to A.

When I press the ion-back-button at C, the application navigates back to B, as it was the previous page.

¿How can I navigate back from C to A when I press the ion-back-button?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using events

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/

in page C use the method willLeave https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/ViewController/#willLeave

inside the willLeave trigger an event example: "user left C"

then in page B listen the event "user left C" and then use

```
  this.navCtrl.pop();
```

you will go back to page A

Comment: After trying it, when I press the ion-back-button at C, it navigates back to B and then navigates to C again (C->B->C)

Comment: navCtrl.pop() should send you back https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/ can you show me snapshots ?

Comment: I wrote this `this.events.subscribe('chat:closed', () => this.navCtrl.goBack());` inside page B constructor  and this `this.events.publish('chat:closed');` inside C ionViewWillLeave. (it looks like the pop() method does not exist in Ionic4)

Comment: did you try .pop() method ?

Comment: It looks like it is not available anymore in Ionic4. I got this error: "_this.navCtrl.pop is not a function"

Comment: hmm I see, can you try with this.navCtrl.setRoot('your_page_name')